# event phase -Capture phase in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I read a document, capture phase is check for the event from target to root node. means buttoncontrol to panel container like....

Application

```
  Panel                    
    TitleWindow
        Button
```

But i have 2 panels under the same application container and 2 panels have a button controls and events.

So now the flash player from where and which event will check first ?

thanks,

ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, it uses the parent property in each of the components to work out the stack to send the event through. So it will be the relevant child for the way down the stack.